# Extract measures on each line from sheet music

Tags: java, python, ocr

I would like to know a way to extract individual line of measures. I am not sure if an algorithm for this already exists so I've thought of scanning a sheet music from left to right, extract all the white spaces from above and below a line of measures.

I am not looking for a way to convert the sheet music into MusicXML or extract other useful information. No, essentially what I am dealing with is a regular document. I need to separate the paragraphs. I am not interested in the information conveyed by the paragraph but simply chunking them separately from the regions of the document. In this case a paragraph would be one line of measures. I don't need individual measures but all the measure on each line of sheet music.

[image]

This is one of the output I would like from the full sheet music but without the title, composer and etc. 
[image]

Comment: Do you also need the notes above/below the staff? Sometimes those can get a little tangled.

Comment: What does 'extract individual line of measures' mean? Not a musical term.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but googleing for 'python sheet music ocr', lead me to another stack question :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675077/ocr-for-sheet-music :: which may help you along

Comment: The problem is actually kind of similar to a problem describing how to find "rivers" (linear streams of whitespace) in text. I suggest you check out this answer too:
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/374/river-detection-in-text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing you have the sheet music in PDF File, I would use [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/PDFToImage.html) to get images from an input PDF File containing the sheet music, then locate the coordinates of the whole bar you need, the with a selected image define the coordinates to crop the image and manipulate it until you get the desired result.

```
PDDocument document = null; 
document = PDDocument.load(inFile); 
List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
Iterator iter = pages.iterator(); 
while (iter.hasNext()) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) iter.next();
            PDResources resources = page.getResources();
            Map pageImages = resources.getImages();
            if (pageImages != null) { 
                Iterator imageIter = pageImages.keySet().iterator();
                while (imageIter.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) imageIter.next();
                    PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage) pageImages.get(key);
                    image.write2OutputStream(/* some output stream */);
                }
            }
}
```

Here is a sample code available in Apache PDFBox.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.AccessPermission;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardDecryptionMaterial;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectImage;

/**
 * This will read a read pdf and extract images. <br/><br/>
 *
 * usage: java org.apache.pdfbox.ExtractImages &lt;pdffile&gt; &lt;password&gt; [imageprefix]
 *
 * @author  <a href="mailto:ben@benlitchfield.com">Ben Litchfield</a>
 * @version $Revision: 1.7 $
 */
public class ExtractImages
{
    private int imageCounter = 1;

    private static final String PASSWORD = "-password";
    private static final String PREFIX = "-prefix";
    private static final String ADDKEY = "-addkey";
    private static final String NONSEQ = "-nonSeq";

    private ExtractImages()
    {
    }

    /**
     * This is the entry point for the application.
     *
     * @param args The command-line arguments.
     *
     * @throws Exception If there is an error decrypting the document.
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        ExtractImages extractor = new ExtractImages();
        extractor.extractImages( args );
    }

    private void extractImages( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        if( args.length < 1 || args.length > 4 )
        {
            usage();
        }
        else
        {
            String pdfFile = null;
            String password = "";
            String prefix = null;
            boolean addKey = false;
            boolean useNonSeqParser = false;
            for( int i=0; i<args.length; i++ )
            {
                if( args[i].equals( PASSWORD ) )
                {
                    i++;
                    if( i >= args.length )
                    {
                        usage();
                    }
                    password = args[i];
                }
                else if( args[i].equals( PREFIX ) )
                {
                    i++;
                    if( i >= args.length )
                    {
                        usage();
                    }
                    prefix = args[i];
                }
                else if( args[i].equals( ADDKEY ) )
                {
                    addKey = true;
                }
                else if( args[i].equals( NONSEQ ) )
                {
                    useNonSeqParser = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if( pdfFile == null )
                    {
                        pdfFile = args[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            if(pdfFile == null)
            {
                usage();
            }
            else
            {
                if( prefix == null && pdfFile.length() >4 )
                {
                    prefix = pdfFile.substring( 0, pdfFile.length() -4 );
                }

                PDDocument document = null;

                try
                {
                    if (useNonSeqParser)
                    {
                        document = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File(pdfFile), null, password);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document = PDDocument.load( pdfFile );

                        if( document.isEncrypted() )
                        {
                            StandardDecryptionMaterial spm = new StandardDecryptionMaterial(password);
                            document.openProtection(spm);
                        }
                    }
                    AccessPermission ap = document.getCurrentAccessPermission();
                    if( ! ap.canExtractContent() )
                    {
                        throw new IOException(
                            "Error: You do not have permission to extract images." );
                    }

                    List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
                    Iterator iter = pages.iterator();
                    while( iter.hasNext() )
                    {
                        PDPage page = (PDPage)iter.next();
                        PDResources resources = page.getResources();
                        // extract all XObjectImages which are part of the page resources
                        processResources(resources, prefix, addKey);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if( document != null )
                    {
                        document.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void processResources(PDResources resources, String prefix, boolean addKey) throws IOException
    {
        if (resources == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Map<String, PDXObject> xobjects = resources.getXObjects();
        if( xobjects != null )
        {
            Iterator<String> xobjectIter = xobjects.keySet().iterator();
            while( xobjectIter.hasNext() )
            {
                String key = xobjectIter.next();
                PDXObject xobject = xobjects.get( key );
                // write the images
                if (xobject instanceof PDXObjectImage)
                {
                    PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage)xobject;
                    String name = null;
                    if (addKey) 
                    {
                        name = getUniqueFileName( prefix + "_" + key, image.getSuffix() );
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        name = getUniqueFileName( prefix, image.getSuffix() );
                    }
                    System.out.println( "Writing image:" + name );
                    image.write2file( name );
                }
                // maybe there are more images embedded in a form object
                else if (xobject instanceof PDXObjectForm)
                {
                    PDXObjectForm xObjectForm = (PDXObjectForm)xobject;
                    PDResources formResources = xObjectForm.getResources();
                    processResources(formResources, prefix, addKey);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String getUniqueFileName( String prefix, String suffix )
    {
        String uniqueName = null;
        File f = null;
        while( f == null || f.exists() )
        {
            uniqueName = prefix + "-" + imageCounter;
            f = new File( uniqueName + "." + suffix );
            imageCounter++;
        }
        return uniqueName;
    }

    /**
     * This will print the usage requirements and exit.
     */
    private static void usage()
    {
        System.err.println( "Usage: java org.apache.pdfbox.ExtractImages [OPTIONS] <PDF file>\n" +
            "  -password  <password>        Password to decrypt document\n" +
            "  -prefix  <image-prefix>      Image prefix(default to pdf name)\n" +
            "  -addkey                      add the internal image key to the file name\n" +
            "  -nonSeq                      Enables the new non-sequential parser\n" +
            "  <PDF file>                   The PDF document to use\n"
            );
        System.exit( 1 );
    }

}
```

Now to crop image you can use:

```
/**
     * Crop the main image according to this rectangle, and scale it to the
     * correct size for a thumbnail.
     */
    public InputStream cropAndScale(InputStream mainImageStream,
            CropRectangle crop) {
        try {
            RenderedOp mainImage = loadImage(mainImageStream);
            RenderedOp opaqueImage = makeImageOpaque(mainImage);
            RenderedOp croppedImage = cropImage(opaqueImage, crop);
            RenderedOp scaledImage = scaleImage(croppedImage);
            byte[] jpegBytes = encodeAsJpeg(scaledImage);
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(jpegBytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to scale the image", e);
        }
    }
```

which is available in [this page](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/vivo/vitro/code/branches/dev-sdb/webapp/src/edu/cornell/mannlib/vitro/webapp/controller/freemarker/ImageUploadThumbnailer.java) and the [project](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/vivo/vitro/code/branches/dev-sdb/webapp/src/edu/cornell/mannlib/vitro/webapp/controller/freemarker/)

There is other option to parse images inside a pdf file, take a look [at this code](https://svn.atlassian.com/svn/public/atlassian/vendor/pdf-renderer/tags/pdf-renderer-1.13-atlassian-1/src/main/java/com/sun/pdfview/) specially [this](https://svn.atlassian.com/svn/public/atlassian/vendor/pdf-renderer/tags/pdf-renderer-1.13-atlassian-1/src/main/java/com/sun/pdfview/PDFImage.java)

Comment: not sure why this answer got selected as it completely fails to answer the users question.